# TestNG tests fail when ran as Maven Test, but pass when running as TestNG suite

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running automated Selenium tests with TestNG.  When I run as TestNG Suite, everything works just fine.  But when I run as Maven Test, they fail.  I'm super confused why they would work under one scenario and not another.  Here is a general layout of the tests:

Base.java

```
public class Base {

    public WebDriver driver = null;

    public WebDriver getLocalDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        return driver;
    }
```

TestBase.java

```
public class TestBase extends Base {

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        Base b = new Base();
        driver = b.getLocalDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

LoginTests.java

```
public class LoginTests extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void TestOne() {

        driver.get("http://www.company.com");
        // ^^^ driver == null right here (line 28)
    }
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.automation.ecom.tests.LoginTests.TestOne(LoginTests.java:28)
```

edit: pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <groupId>com.company.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ecom</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="ECOM Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

    <test verbose="2" name="Chrome">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
        <parameter name="nodeURL" value="http://10.11.25.170:5552/wd/hub"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.company.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>

    <test verbose="2" name="Firefox">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="nodeURL" value="http://10.11.25.170:5551/wd/hub"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.company.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `run as Maven Test`  ? How does your pom file look like ? Which plugin do you use for running?

Comment: In Eclipse.  When I right click on the project and select `Run As` -> `Maven Test` it fails.  But when I right click on `testng.xml` and select `Run As` -> `TestNG Suite` it passes.  I'm trying to get the project to run in maven so I will have more options when integrating the project with Jenkins.

Also, added the pom.xml.

Comment: Are there any tests more? How does the `testng.xml` look like?

Comment: As of right now, there are no more tests.  This is step 1 of the project, getting the framework up and running.  Then I would write more tests.  I added the testng.xml as well.  Part of the framework involves distributed testing using selenium grid, but right now I have all that removed so I can try to figure out how to get the test to run when invoking men test.

Comment: Once again, I can't figure out why the tests would fail when running via maven, but NOT fail when running via TestNG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm super confused why they would work under one scenario and not
>   another.

So was I when I first discovered that TestNG makes (good) use of multithreading.

Try changing `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` annotations to `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod`. This would be the simplest solution.

Besides persisting the `WebDriver` in static `ThreadLocal` may be key to success.

Consider this:

```
public class TestBase {

    protected static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
    protected String abc;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("I am in setUp method.");

        //WebDriver instantiation etc.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "--disable-cache");
        webDriver.set(new ChromeDriver(options));
        webDriver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){
        System.out.println("I am in tearDown method.");
        //You can clean up after tests.
        //webDriver.get().quit();
        webDriver.get().quit();
    }
}
```

In two separate files:

```
public class Test1 extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void goToGoogle() {
        System.out.println("Google");
        String googleURL = "http://google.com/";
        webDriver.get().get(googleURL);
        assertTrue(webDriver.get().getCurrentUrl().contains("google"), "We are on Google!");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Test2 extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void goToStackOverflow() {
        System.out.println("SO!");
        String stackOverflowAddress = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
        webDriver.get().get(stackOverflowAddress);
        assertTrue(webDriver.get().getCurrentUrl().contains("stack"), "We are on SO!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mate you can use :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      </dependency>
```

I got my maven tests executed like this.

Thanks